# Elastic search Java

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Below is a json schema I have in elastic search

```
{
    "fullName": "",
    "avatar": "",
    "email": "",
    "resumeLink": "",
    "phone": "",
    "role": "",
    "noticePeriod": "",
    "dateOfBirth": "",
    "gender": "",
    "maritalStatus": "",
    "address": "",
    "location": "",
    "industryType": "",
    "personalSummary": "",
    "workSummary": "",
    "functionalArea": "",
    "currentPosition": "",
    "currentEmployer": "",
    "keySkills": [],
    "otherSkills": [],
    "iTSkill": [
      {
        "skill": "",
        "version": ""
      }
    ],
    "highestEducationDetails": "",
    "educationDetails": {
      "Under graduation": {
        "school": "",
        "degreeType": ""
      },
      "Post graduation": {
        "school": "",
        "degreeType": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is a boolean query i wrote in java to search for keywords, and also search individual fields like Location, Role, addresses, skills and other fields in the json schema returnning a random_score for the documents

```
  if (Strings.isEmpty(searchQueryRequest.getText())) {
                query = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction());//This line does not return random result;



            } else {
                query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        //.minimumShouldMatch(1)
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("location")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("location", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("role")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("role", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("functionalArea")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("functionalArea", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("workHistory.organization")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("workHistory.organization", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("workHistory.designation")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("workHistory.designation", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("keySkills")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("otherSkills")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))

                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("itSkill.skill")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))
                        
                        
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText()).field("industryType")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("industryType", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText())
                                .field("educationDetails.Under graduation.school")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("educationDetails.Under graduation.school", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))

                        
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText())
                                .field("educationDetails.Under graduation.degreeType")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))

                        
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("educationDetails.Under graduation.degreeType", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))

                        
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText())
                                .field("educationDetails.Post graduation.school")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("educationDetails.Post graduation.school", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))


                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(searchQueryRequest.getText())
                                .field("educationDetails.Post graduation.degreeType")
                                .defaultOperator(Operator.OR), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()))

                        
                        .should(QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("educationDetails.Post graduation.degreeType", searchQueryRequest.getText()),
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction()));
            }
```

How can i make this better?

Comment: By using a loop over all the strings, for which you do exactly the same.

Comment: alright thanks, can you give me a `snippet` on how to go about it?